# React + MaterializeCSS + dynamic rendering dropdowns (fault position)

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, materialize, jsx

I am using ReactJS with JSX and materializeCss for styling.
I am facing this problem for a couple of days now...
In short what I have:

```
class PreventiveCollection extends Component {
    componentDidUpdate = () => updateDropdowns(); // which stands for initializing materialize dropdowns
    render() {
        const myList = this.props.data.map( (i ,index) => ( 
            <li key={index} className="collection-item">
                <i data-target={i.id} className="dropdown-trigger material-icons right">more_vert</i>
                <ul id={i.id} className='dropdown-content'>
                    <li><a>option 1</a></li>
                    <li><a>option 2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        ));
        return <div>{myList}</div>
    }
}
```

I am rendering a collection of items, where each item has a dropdown menu. The problem is that when I click "more_vert" button, the dropdown opens on the top of the component, right below the first menu button. 
They all work and are connected with each item correctly. The problem is only the position. Please see attached screen

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFfV4.png

On the left screen, the top menu-button was clicked, it's all fine.

On the right screen, the 3rd item menu-button was clicked. The dropdown content is fine, but the position is wrong. it always sticks to this first menu button...

I have tried:

- move the menu to separate component with its own update state functions
- moved updateDropdowns() from componentDidUpdate to the end of the
  render() method.
- wrap menus  objects with divs with mix of position relative/absolute

none of the above worked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to MaterialCss and the first relative parent. The solution is to wrap full menu code with div with position relative, like so:

```
class PreventiveCollection extends Component {
    componentDidUpdate = () => updateDropdowns(); // which stands for initializing materialize dropdowns
    render() {
        const myList = this.props.data.map( (i ,index) => ( 
            <li key={index} className="collection-item">
                <div style={{position: 'relative'}}>
                    <i data-target={i.id} className="dropdown-trigger material-icons right">more_vert</i>
                    <ul id={i.id} className='dropdown-content'>
                        <li><a>option 1</a></li>
                        <li><a>option 2</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        ));
        return <div>{myList}</div>
    }
}
```